# Python: aliased to python3

Tags: python, linux, zsh, zshrc

I tried to upgrade python 2.7 to python 3 and I modified the file `~/.bash_aliases` but when I type python in elementary terminal I get this error

```
zsh: command not found: python3
```

and when I type which python

```
python: aliased to python3
```

actually I prefer return to python 2.7 or if someone know how can I fix this :c

Comment: You are using `zsh`.  Does `zsh` read `.bash_aliases` or `.bashrc`?

Comment: If neither of those files, run a `grep python3 ~/.*` through all dot-files files in your home directory; possibly the alias turns up.

Comment: Please post the contents of your `~/.zshrc` file, if it exists.

Comment: Can you run the `python3` command successfully without the alias?

Comment: i delete the file bash_aliases and i could run python. But im very intersted to update python 3.4 :c

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go into your .zshrc file.  Is there a line that reads:

`alias python='python3'`

If so, remove that line.  Else, check if you can run `python2`, `python2.7`, or something like that.  If so, then just hack and add the line

`alias python='python2'`

Or whatever your python2 is.  Else, type

`sudo apt-get install python2.7`

Or whatever is the appropriate method for installing programs on your system.

Comment: On mac, when I do this, I can't run that came installed with Python3. See my answer below

Comment: After you make changes to `~/.zshrc` and save the file, don't forget to run `source ~/.zshrc` to apply the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps if you are using macOS.

1. Install Python with brew: `brew install python`. This will install the latest version of Python. If you want Python 2.7, do well to specify the version.
2. Check the path where this Python was installed: `brew info python`. You will see a path similar to: `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin`
3. Make home brew Python default:

```
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

4. Source the file to apply changes without restarting the terminal: `source ~/.zshrc`